# Optimize this loop in jquery

Tags: jquery, loops, for-loop, fadein, fadeout

I need to optimize the following code. Tried using FOR, but the image shows all at once.

Used the following solution, but this not optimized.

```
$(document).ready(function(){



function fadeInOut () {

     var $element1 = $('a#imagem01');
     var $element2 = $('a#imagem02');
     var $element3 = $('a#imagem03');
     var $element4 = $('a#imagem04');
     var $element5 = $('a#imagem05');
     var $element6 = $('a#imagem06');



     $element1.fadeIn(2000, function () {
     $element1.fadeOut(2000, function () {

     $element2.fadeIn(2000, function () {
     $element2.fadeOut(2000, function () {


     $element3.fadeIn(2000, function () {
     $element3.fadeOut(2000, function () {


     $element4.fadeIn(2000, function () {
     $element4.fadeOut(2000, function () {

     $element5.fadeIn(2000, function () {
     $element5.fadeOut(2000, function () {

     $element6.fadeIn(2000, function () {
     $element6.fadeOut(2000, function () {

     fadeInOut();  

     });});});});});});});});});});});});

     }

     fadeInOut();

});
```

I need Help Please!

Comment: Take a look at the .each() docs. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div").hide();
    var obj = [$("#o1"), $("#o2"), $("#o3"), $("#o4"), $("#o5")];
    var i = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
            obj[i].fadeIn(2000);
            obj[i].fadeOut(2000);
            i++;
            if (i > 4) {
                clearInterval(interval)
            }
        },
        4000
    );
});
```

I am pretty sure the solution above is better, but [this would work too](http://jsfiddle.net/qnx83/2/)..

Answer (score 1):

```
function fadeInOut() {
    var elements = ['a#imagem01', 'a#imagem02', 'a#imagem03', 'a#imagem04', 'a#imagem05', 'a#imagem06'];
    var index = 0;
    var loopForever = false;

    (function() {
        var selfFunction = arguments.callee;
        if((loopForever) && (index > elements.length-1)) index = 0;

        if(index <= elements.length-1) {
            $(elements[index++]).fadeIn(2000, function() {
                $(this).fadeOut(2000, selfFunction);
            });
        }
    })();
}
```

Untested, but something along these lines should do the trick. It's basically a callback loop that iterates over all the elements.

Comment: Good work.
i put, if(index ==0), for loop infinite in ,if.

Thanks.

Comment: @user2108537 glad it helped, if you are asking how to loop it forever with these elements, see update. Set loopForever to true at the beginning and it should work. Also I'd appreciate if you set the answer as accepted (green tick next to it) :)